# Why did my branches completely merge?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch

I'm new to mercurial. I try to work on 2 versions of my software. I have named 2 branches : one is "v8" (old/stable) other is "default".

I thought I understood things but now I seem to have merged both versions.

This is what it looks like (removed info from before branch) :

```
o  changeset:   39:1e72986020bd
|  tag:         tip
|  parent:      37:406b8e897030
|  user:        ME <me@example.com>
|  date:        Thu Jan 16 09:53:55 2014 +0100
|  summary:     Suppression des DCU
|
| o  changeset:   38:7381e3f2309b
|/|  branch:      v8
| |  parent:      31:611a4416e4a5
| |  parent:      37:406b8e897030
| |  user:        ME <me@example.com>
| |  date:        Wed Jan 15 19:21:58 2014 +0100
| |  summary:     fixforbrowser sur impressiondecomptes
| |
o |  changeset:   37:406b8e897030
| |  user:        ME <me@example.com>
| |  date:        Wed Jan 15 19:02:18 2014 +0100
| |  summary:     fixforbrowser sur impressiondecomptes
| |
o |  changeset:   36:d7c0feaad38a
| |  user:        ME <me@example.com>
| |  date:        Wed Jan 15 18:57:44 2014 +0100
| |  summary:     Cosmétique
| |
o |  changeset:   35:d2b4c3130b61
| |  user:        ME <me@example.com>
| |  date:        Sun Jan 12 14:38:36 2014 +0100
| |  summary:     Cosmétique encore
| |
o |  changeset:   34:5447f904a336
| |  user:        ME <me@example.com>
| |  date:        Fri Jan 10 03:51:33 2014 +0100
| |  summary:     projet
| |
o |  changeset:   33:f48c4023d822
| |  user:        ME <me@example.com>
| |  date:        Fri Jan 10 03:50:06 2014 +0100
| |  summary:     cosmétique (beaucoup de fiches)
| |
o |  changeset:   32:cc6b2de08004
| |  parent:      30:5b4bef6aad09
| |  user:        ME <me@example.com>
| |  date:        Fri Jan 10 02:12:59 2014 +0100
| |  summary:     cosmétique
| |
| @  changeset:   31:611a4416e4a5
| |  branch:      v8
| |  parent:      29:0c47053f9a7b
| |  user:        ME <me@example.com>
| |  date:        Fri Jan 10 02:11:01 2014 +0100
| |  summary:     purge deleted ?
| |
o |  changeset:   30:5b4bef6aad09
|\|  parent:      25:74d793961989
| |  parent:      29:0c47053f9a7b
| |  user:        ME <me@example.com>
| |  date:        Fri Jan 10 02:09:04 2014 +0100
| |  summary:     v9 after fixes
| |
| o  changeset:   29:0c47053f9a7b
| |  branch:      v8
| |  parent:      27:79855eedf019
| |  user:        ME <me@example.com>
| |  date:        Fri Jan 10 01:57:22 2014 +0100
| |  summary:     8.084 ok?
| |
+---o  changeset:   28:e60a7447adf4
| |/   branch:      v8
| |    parent:      25:74d793961989
| |    parent:      27:79855eedf019
| |    user:        ME <me@example.com>
| |    date:        Fri Jan 10 01:41:05 2014 +0100
| |    summary:     8.084 ??
| |
| o  changeset:   27:79855eedf019
| |  branch:      v8
| |  user:        ME <me@example.com>
| |  date:        Wed Jan 08 16:57:12 2014 +0100
| |  summary:     fix detection des fichiers de récap sur imports feuillets
| |
| o  changeset:   26:19d2f4b2d867
| |  branch:      v8
| |  parent:      23:14219f06bc1d
| |  user:        ME <me@example.com>
| |  date:        Wed Jan 08 16:49:35 2014 +0100
| |  summary:     fix qpdep et qpdrm sur imports feuillets
| |
o |  changeset:   25:74d793961989
| |  user:        ME <me@example.com>
| |  date:        Wed Jan 08 16:44:30 2014 +0100
| |  summary:     premieres modifs v9
| |
o |  changeset:   24:1af3020ba120
| |  parent:      22:7307bc3e87ba
| |  user:        ME <me@example.com>
| |  date:        Thu Dec 26 15:47:20 2013 +0100
| |  summary:     Initial v9
| |
| o  changeset:   23:14219f06bc1d
|/   branch:      v8
|    user:        ME <me@example.com>
|    date:        Thu Dec 26 15:41:55 2013 +0100
|    summary:     Branche stable v8
|
o  changeset:   22:7307bc3e87ba
|  user:        ME <me@example.com>
|  date:        Fri Dec 20 18:50:50 2013 +0100
|  summary:     8.083
```

- Rev 31 seems to be the last "good" v8
- then I did `hg update default` and worked on "default" branch.
- I committed up to rev 36 because I knew I had to make a fix I would want to merge with stable/v8
- I did the change, committed (rev 37)
- then I switched to v8 with `hg update v8`
- then I tried to merge the change from default with `hg merge 406b8e897030`
- then I committed (rev 38)
- I did a last commit after removing 3 binary (DCU) files that were in one of the repository although *.dcu are `.hgignore`d.

Now, when I switch branches, I see no file change. I can go back to rev 31 with `hg update v8` (probably useless) and `hg update --rev 31` but I would like :

- to understand what I did wrong
- to get 2 clean branches back

If you know of a clear explanation of how branches and merge work, I'd love to read it.

Answer (score 2):

- Branches stores diverged history of changes in sources (of anything)
- Merging branches brings to target branch fro source branch **all changes**, appeared from latest divergence point: it can be branchpoint or latest mergeset's parent
- If you have to port *only subset* of changes from branch to branch (1+ changeset, but < ALL), you have to [`hg graft`](http://selenic.com/hg/help/graft) only these changesets

Comment: ok, `hg graft` seems to be **the** command to use almost exclusively in my case. Now, how do I clean up my repository ? Is there a way to "forget" (or revert) the merge 'and `parent: 37:406b8e897030` ?

Comment: @JCBoggio - rebase r39 to r36. strip r37 (enable strip extension before, rebasing needed because "strip extension - strip changesets **and their descendents** from history" and you have to eliminate only 37-38)